# Django request.Get passing variables to next page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a basic question on request.Get in Django. I have given my form declaration below

Now, I need to pass the v.position to the next page. How can validate the request.get if my v.position is populated

For example:- is the below code is correct?

volpostion =  request.GET['Volunteer Position'].strip()

if volposition
    perform the required function.

I read that request.Get gets a dictionary of the form fields..form fields here mean the lable name?

Forms.py

```
<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_Volposition">Volunteer Position:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left"><a href="/signups/new/{{ v.position }}" class="username" <u>{{ v.volposition }}</u></a></th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>

<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_roledesc">Role Description:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left">{{ v.roledesc }}</th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
```

More information:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^new/$',                           sfp.view),
   (r'^volunteer/$',     volunteer_page),
   (r'^vollist/$', volunteer_list),
   (r'^volcont/$', volunteer_contact)
```

views.py

```
sfp = SimpleFormProcessing(
    form_class=VolunteerSignupForm,
    form_2_model=volunteersignupform_2_model,
    form2_class=VolunteerForm,
    form_template='signups/create_contact_form.dmpl',
    email_template='signups/response_email.dmpl',
    email_html_template='signups/response_email_html.dmpl',
    email_subject='Vibha Volunteer Signup',
    email_sender='volunteer@vibha.org',
    redirect_url='/signups/thanks/',
    do_captcha=True)
```

SimpleFormProcessing.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from formwrappers import form_with_captcha, form_with_ipaddress
import pdb


class SimpleFormProcessing:

    def __init__(self, form_class, form_2_model, form2_class, form_template,
            email_template, email_subject, email_sender, redirect_url,
            do_captcha=False, record_ip_addr=False, email_html_template=None):
        self.form_class = form_class
        self.form_2_model = form_2_model
        self.form_template = form_template
        self.email_template = email_template
        self.email_html_template = email_html_template
        self.email_subject = email_subject
        self.email_sender = email_sender
        self.redirect_url = redirect_url
        self.do_captcha = do_captcha
        self.record_ip_addr = record_ip_addr

    def view(self, request, initial={}):
        pdb.set_trace()
        Form = self.form_class
        if self.do_captcha:
            Form = form_with_captcha(Form, request)
        if self.record_ip_addr:
            Form = form_with_ipaddress(Form, request)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # Try processing the form
            if self.do_captcha and not accepts_cookies(request):
                return our_flatpage('Please enable cookies and try again.')
            else:
                form = Form(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    # The form is correct, process it
                    model = self.form_2_model(form)
                    if self.email_template:
                        text_content = render_to_string(self.email_template, {'model': model})
                        recipients = model.emailRecipients()
                        try:
                            bcc_recipients = model.emailBCCRecipients()
                        except:
                            bcc_recipients = None
                        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(self.email_subject, text_content, self.email_sender,
                                recipients, bcc_recipients)

                        if self.email_html_template:
                            html_content = render_to_string(self.email_html_template, {'model': model})
                            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

                        msg.send()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_url)
                else:
                    # Show the form with errors
                    return render_to_response(self.form_template, {'form': form})
        else:
            # Show the empty form

            form = Form(initial=initial)
            if self.do_captcha:
                accepts_cookies(request)
```

volunteer_list.dmpl

```
{% extends "base.dmpl" %}
{% block title %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Registration{% endblock %}
{% block contentBox %}
<h2>Volunteer Opportunities</h2>
<p>Vibha is currently looking for volunteers interested in helping the organization in the following areas:</p>
<div class="relation">
<ul>
{% for k in teamrel %}
        <li align="left"><a href="#{{ k }} "> <b> {{ k}} </b> </a> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

<p>If you are interested in any of these opportunities please contact us by clicking on the position you are interested and filling out the form.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table>

{% for v in vollist %}
{% ifchanged  v.teamrelation %}
<tr>
<th colspan=7 align="left"><h3><a name="{{ v.teamrelation }}"> {{v.teamrelation}} </a> </h3></th>
</tr>
{% endifchanged %}


<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_Volposition">Volunteer Position:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left"><a href="/signups/new/{{ v.position }}" class="username" <u>{{ v.volposition }}</u></a></th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>

<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_roledesc">Role Description:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left">{{ v.roledesc }}</th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_timereqt">Time Requirements:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left">{{ v.noofhours }} hours per month</th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_qualreqt">Qualification and Requirements:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left">{{ v.Qualreqt }}</th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_duration">Duration of the Role:</label></th>
        <th colspan=20 align="left">  {{ v.Duration}} {{ v.Durationyrmon}}</th>
<tr> <td colspan="10" height="20" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your `forms.py` contains html? I see neither a form nor a django form on your question. Also what is "v". Are we supposed to know?

Comment: sorry, Im not using the form..Its a html page..The volunteer position will be passed. I need to know how to access the volunteer position if its populated in the views.

Comment: Start by reading the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ and posting more code, what does your view look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite difficult to decipher, but from what I can make of it, here's some pointers:

1. The keys of both the `request.GET` and `request.POST` dictionaries (depending on which method was used) will be the HTML `name` attributes of the fields, not their labels. You didn't post any code that include any fields, but in general, if you had something like:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="volposition" value="0">
   ```

   Then, you would find the value with:

   ```
   request.POST['volposition']
   ```
2. Always use the `.get()` method on dictionaries when you're not sure that key will be there or not. The code you have will raise an `IndexError` exception if the key doesn't exist. For example:

   ```
   volposition = request.GET.get('volposition')
   ```
3. Forms should virtually always be sent via the `POST` method. The *rare* exception is things like search forms, where having the submitted values as a query string makes more sense (those are typically sent via the `GET` method). The rule of thumb is that if you're requesting a resource for read-only purposes, use `GET`. For example, searching Google, doesn't *change* anything, you're just requesting a list of search results, so `GET` is used. However, if you're doing any sort of modification (creating, editing, or even just updating session data... anything that actually affects some sort of *change*) then you use `POST`. You also shouldn't mix the two. For instance, don't `POST` to a URL with a query string.

All that said. You should be able to cover your bases with the following:

```
{% if request.REQUEST.volposition %}
<input type="hidden" name="volposition" value="{{ request.REQUEST.volposition }}">
{% endif %}
```

`request.REQUEST` contains the parameters passed with the URL, whether by `GET` or `POST`. Always use `request.GET` or `request.POST` when you *know* what method data will be sent by, but in situations like this one, where you just want the value and it could come from either method, `request.REQUEST` is acceptable.

If the key *does* exist, then a hidden input will be rendered with its value. No matter how the data is sent, `volposition` will be passed along now.

Comment: As a general note it is considered good form to upvote/accept the answer you've got - that way the question is considered answered and the user gets the kudos for their work.